# External server did not return any content

Tags: soap-api, webservices, soap

I am trying to call a webservice methods generated from WSDL. I am able to get the success reponse from SOAP UI. But I am getting the below error from Apex

> System.CalloutException: IO Exception: External server did not return
>   any content

Below is the WSDL Methods

```
public class Yardi_GetDataSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.xxxpce.com/61395xxxxxproject/webservices/xxx_GetData.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'YSI.PSG.Custom.ME.Webservice', 'MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL'};
        public MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResult_element FetchData_DataSet(String sCredentialName,String sUserName,String sUserPassword,String sViewName,MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.mainXmldoc_element mainXmldoc) {
            MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSet_element request_x = new MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSet_element();
            request_x.sCredentialName = sCredentialName;
            request_x.sUserName = sUserName;
            request_x.sUserPassword = sUserPassword;
            request_x.sViewName = sViewName;
            request_x.mainXmldoc = mainXmldoc;
            MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'YSI.PSG.Custom.ME.Webservice/FetchData_DataSet',
              'YSI.PSG.Custom.ME.Webservice',
              'FetchData_DataSet',
              'YSI.PSG.Custom.ME.Webservice',
              'FetchData_DataSetResponse',
              'MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.FetchData_DataSetResult;
        }
```

This is how I am calling the webservice from Apex

```
MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.Yardi_GetDataSoap a = new
    MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.Yardi_GetDataSoap
    ();
a.timeout_x = 120000;
MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResult_element test = 
    new MAFLS_YardiGetDataSampleWSDL.FetchData_DataSetResult_element();

test = a.FetchData_DataSet('xxxInterfacezzz',
                        'xxxInterfacezzz','gdsdagyg21323dssc',
                        'xxxTestViewzzz',null);
```

Below is the sample working request from SOAP Ui

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ysi="YSI.PSG.Custom.ME.Webservice">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ysi:FetchData_DataSet>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ysi:sCredentialName>xxxName</ysi:sCredentialName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ysi:sUserName>xxxUName</ysi:sUserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ysi:sUserPassword>xxxPassword</ysi:sUserPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ysi:sViewName>xxxView</ysi:sViewName>
         <!--Optional:-->

      </ysi:FetchData_DataSet>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is there ip based restriction on your 3rd party server? You might have to ask 3rd party to whitelisst sf ip address

Comment: Thanks @pranayJaiswal for a response. I found a lot of IPs at salesforce official website. Can you suggest an IP range for all IPs of Salesforce?

Comment: @Samir The official IP ranges are in [What are the Salesforce IP Addresses & Domains to whitelist?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was from the server side.
Endpoint in the wsdl was not correct. 
The endpoint in the wsdl is `http`. It should be `https`